# Tax liability in US for LLC's owned by an Indian Citzen

Tags: united-states, taxes, limited-liability-company, liability

I am located in Pune, India and looking forward to form an LLC (Service Industry) in FL only as a face for my Indian Company in the US market. My clients would be making the payments in my Indian Bank Account for the services my company provides and thus I would be paying taxes to the Indian Govt.

1. Would I be still liable to pay taxes in US?
2. Would I have to file tax returns in the US?
3. Would I need a Business bank account in any American Bank?
4. Would I have to obtain a US TAX ID (EIN)?

Any additional information related to this topic would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The LLC will not be liable for anything, it is disregarded for tax purposes.

If you're doing any work while in the US, or you (or your spouse) are a green card holder or a US citizen - then *you* (not the LLC) may be liable, may be required to file, pay, etc.

Unless you're employing someone, or have more than one member in your LLC, you do not need an EIN.

Re the bank - whatever you want. If you want you can open an account in an American bank. If you don't - don't. Who cares?

Answer (score 0):

I am from India. I visited US 6-8 times on business VISA and then started 2 Member LLC. Myself and My wife as LLC Members. We provide Online Training to american students from India. Also Got EIN number. Never employed any one. Do i need to pay taxes? Students from USA pays online by Paypal and i am paying taxes in India. Do i need to pay Taxes in US? DO i need to file the Tax returns? Please guide me. I formed LLC in 2010.

I opened an Office-taken Virtual office for 75 USD per month to open LLC in 2010. As there is physical virtual address, am i liable for US taxes? All my earning is Online, free lancing.

Comment: This should be new question, not the answer!